# multiple if condition in for statement for vue.js state management to get data and return

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js, state-management

I am using state management in vue.js for fetching products. i am fetching products with ID from data base. i need to make two conditions for return if $state has already products.

1. first condition is if $state.products has any products than make it return, and
2. second condition if one ID is passed and related date according to ID is fetched, if again same ID is passed it will return value.

but i am confused how to set condition for multiple match. i also tried logical AND operator for this, but nothing work.
please help me to solve this.

Here is my code.

Product.vue

```
   

     mounted () {
                    this.$store.dispatch("loadProducts",this.category);
                },
                computed:{
                    ...mapState([
                        'products'
                    ])
                },
```

this is my file where i am handling state management for fetching products.
index.js

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        pageTitle: '',
        products: [],
    },
    mutations: {
        setTitle(state, title) {
            state.pageTitle = title;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        loadProducts({ commit }, id) {
            if (this.state.products.length != 0) {
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < this.state.products.length; i++) {
                    var j = this.state.products[i].category_id;                   
                }
            } else if (this.state.products.length != 0 && id == j) {
                console.log("RETURN");
                return;
            } else {
                axios.get('/loadProducts/' + id)
                    .then(({ data }) => {
                        this.state.products = data.items;
                        console.log(this.state.products);
                        commit('set_products', data.items)
                    })
            }
        },
    },
    mutations: {
        set_products(state, products) {
            state.products = products;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You do not need an `else if` but a nested condition: `if (products.length > 0) { if (products contains ID) { return value; } return; } else { ... }`

Comment: Why you have double mutations key?

Comment: var i;
            for (i = 0; i < this.state.products.length; i++) {
                if (this.state.products.length > 0 && this.state.products[i].category_id == 1 && this.state.products[i].category_id == 2) {
                    console.log("RETURN")
                    return;
                }
            }
i used this code, but still not working.